# How to migrate Angular-2 app on Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am going to use Sing App - Web & Angular 2.0 Dashboard template for our assignment but this app is not based on Angular CLI project. I have to bring this app on Angular CLI.I have tried some option but not succeeds. Please suggest the best way bring this app over Angular CLI.

Comment: What is Sing App?

Comment: sing app is admin dashboard template based on agular 2@https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/sing-app-web-angular-2.0-dashboard-WB0J6BJ85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE 08/07/2017:*** *If you are looking how to upgrade angular cli breaking changes when you migrating to a newer version check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431592/415078)*

1. Run `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` then`npm cache clean`
2. Run `npm install -g angular-cli` more details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation)
3. Backup your `app`
4. Go to your `app` folder
5. Run `ng init` - this command will initialize the `angular-cli` app by writing some files in to your existing app. Be careful with overriding the existing files, skip the ones you are not sure, however you always can refer to your backup.
6. Run `ng new simple-app` - this one you will be using as a `angular-cli` source of truth app.
7. Compare files produced/required by `angular-cli` in your `app` with `simple-app` to see if anything gets missed during step **4.**
8. Make sure that all requited `angular-cli` npm modules gets installed in to your `app` (compare `package.json` files)
9. Run `npm start` it might give you an errors you have to fix. You might need to go back to steps **7.** and **8.** here. If you mess up the packages you might need to remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.
10. You can access your `app` at http://localhost:4200

Comment: Following your step but CLI is hanged after "70% building modules 763/763 modules 0 active"

Comment: it might be an issue with some of your `npm packages`, check that all your packages are compatiable with your current `angular 2.x.x` version, also check your typescript version, make sure it is `2.0.10`. You might have some of your packages verisons prefixed with `^`, so just go to `npm_modules` and check the `pakage.json` of a particular package to manually to check it's the exact version. Also you can disable packages manually one-by-one by putting comments in `app.module.ts` just to find out which is failing during the build.

Comment: Thanks ...Working Now

Comment: Hi im trying to do the same but unable to, can u please elaborate on which files to replace and which not to?

Comment: @Kuncevic i tried the steps above, but i guess the cli version has changed drastically, could you provide the steps. One way i tried is using all there css and JS from ajax version of Sing App, but not everything works as required. Please do help!

Comment: @PratikKelwalkar did you still have an issue? If so please create a new question with all the details, errors you are getting, etc.